# React addEventListener handler function called TWICE

Tags: reactjs

Having such simple `React` main App file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import {Header} from "./Components/header"
import {Footer} from "./Components/footer"
import {Sidebar} from "./Components/sidebar"
import {About} from "./Components/about"
import {User} from "./Components/user"

const listener = () => {
    console.log("Main listener")
};

function App() {

    const media = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 700px)');
    media.addEventListener("change", listener);

    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">

                <Header />
                <Sidebar />
                <Footer />

                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/"></Route>
                    <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}></Route>
                    <Route path="/user" element={<User/>}></Route>
                </Routes>

                <div className="App">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/user">User</Link>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The thing that makes me wonder is that the `change` event handler function (`listener`) is called TWICE! when I resize the browser window. Why isn't the handler function called just once as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect App to be called only once. It will be called in every rerender (by React renderer when it wants to).

Normally, event listers are added when the component is mounted and they are removed when the component is getting unmounted to avoid possible memory leaks.

It can be done using a `useEffect` as below.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
...
...

const listener = () => {
    console.log("Main listener");
};

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const media = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)");

        // add the event listener
        media.addEventListener("change", listener);
        
        return () => {
            // remove the event listener
            media.removeEventListener("change", listener);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        ...
        ...
    );
}

export default App;
```